# Macbook battery problem

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I have a **MacBook 13" (A1181)** running Mac OS X 10.6.8, I have a problem with the battery

When its turned off it responds to power button only when charger plugged in.

After starting i can remove the charger, and it keeps working on the battery.

But there is an **x** on the battery, and it shows

> No Batteries Available
>
> Power Source: Battery

I've tried the following:

- I checked the battery with an other mac, and every thing was fine
- I did SMC reset with no results
- I even replaced the battery cable and the magsafe

Nothing resolved the problem

What should i try now??

Any idea will be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your SMC reset did not work.

Check your SMC reset procedure.

You have a 5 Years old battery!- it is EOL, get a new one.

Comment: As I told its not the battery, because on other mac it works fine.  
For SMC reset I did the process described at 
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964  
1-Shut down the computer  
2-Disconnect the MagSafe power adapter from the computer, if it's connected  
3-Remove the battery  
4-Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds  
5-Release the power button  
6-Reconnect the battery and MagSafe power adapter  
7-Press the power button to turn on the computer

Comment: A 5 Years old battery is not fine! It might work for a short while. Publish your battery profile from the about this Mac.

Comment: There is no battery profile in the About this mac section.
It says battery not installed, even that i can work on the battery for an hour!!

Comment: I have an other macbook of the same model, i tried switching pieces of the both macs but no thng works. Now i'me sure the problem is in the logic board, i dont think its a hard problem, it should be the PRAM

Comment: When i switch the PRAMs the computer doesn't even start. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you reset the PRAM ? Reset the Mac's PRAM (aka NVRAM aka firmware settings). You can do this by holding Command-Option-P-R at startup, and holding them down until the computer has restarted & chimed three times (actually, it's reset by the second chime, but three is traditional). Also check your Firmware version.

Comment: All that didn't work. Its a defective logic board. I think I just need a new mac, since its not easy to find a new logic board.
Thanks.